# rspec not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test the login method below, but it does not seem to be saving the data_provider_user to the database. I've checked using debugger and it works perfectly until it leaves the method and goes back to the rspec code, as shown below.   I've also checked to see if the object is valid after it save using .valid? and it is so I'm a bit lost!

```
def login
 require 'TwitterOauth'
 @data_provider_user = DataProviderUser.find(params[:id])

 if @data_provider_user.twitter?

  @request_token = TwitterOauth.request_url

  @data_provider_user.access_token = @request_token.token
  @data_provider_user.oauth_token_secret = @request_token.secret

  if @data_provider_user.save
    debugger
    redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url              
  end      

 end
end
```

Test:

```
it "should update the tokens" do
    require 'TwitterOauth'
    TwitterOauth.stub(:request_url).and_return(@token)
    debugger
    get :login, {id: @data_provider_user.id}
    debugger
    @data_provider_user.access_token.should_not eq(nil)
    @data_provider_user.oauth_token_secret.should_not eq(nil)
  end
```

Debugger output:

```
#<DataProviderUser id: 84, user_id: 63, data_provider_id: 63, username: nil, password: nil, created_at: "2013-02-19 15:21:59", updated_at: "2013-02-19 15:21:59", access_token: nil, update_frequency: nil, oauth_token_secret: nil>

#<DataProviderUser id: 84, user_id: 63, data_provider_id: 63, username: nil, password: nil, created_at: "2013-02-19 15:21:59", updated_at: "2013-02-19 15:22:12", access_token: "186553918-sEAEO2fcvtyO1x99eH4Q4XwVcOYatODCQ5f1TwqD", update_frequency: nil, oauth_token_secret: "gLw2PtUyTZfxIan1gJBnbP7icboXbi98KlUoOn7ycVs">

#<DataProviderUser id: 84, user_id: 63, data_provider_id: 63, username: nil, password: nil, created_at: "2013-02-19 15:21:59", updated_at: "2013-02-19 15:21:59", access_token: nil, update_frequency: nil, oauth_token_secret: nil>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

------ UPDATE -------

There was actually nothing wrong with the code, the issue was that rspec was not reloading it in time. A way to get around this was to use:

```
@data_provider_user.reload
```

before hand which refreshes the object, updating the values accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was actually nothing wrong with the code, the issue was that rspec was not reloading it in time. A way to get around this was to use:

```
@data_provider_user.reload
```

before hand which refreshes the object, updating the values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In spec/rails_helper.rb

Set **false** to **use_transactional_fixtures**:

```
# If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
# examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
# instead of true.
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking at the right database?  When you're doing testing it's probably going to `myapp_test` (myapp being whatever you called your app).  You may be looking at your `myapp_development` database.

If you're accessing the database via `rails db` chances are you're going into your development database.  You can check with `select database();` if you're using MySQL.  If you want to check your test database, then use `RAILS_ENV=test rails db`.  Again, you can use the select statement to verify you're in the right database.

Comment: I'm using the rails debugger when checking, every time it hits a debugger I type in eval @data_provider_user and the output is above. I'm not using the mysql promt, although I have looked but I can't see any sort of saving going on what-so-ever.